# React native ListView component not working on android

Tags: android, listview, react-native

I am making an android react-native app.  Currently my code runs fine but when I change

```
var {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TextInput,
} = React;
```

to..

```
var {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TextInput,
  ListView
} = React;
```

Then it breaks and I start getting the red screen of death.

The error message is:

> 'ScrollView' has no propType for native prop
>   'RTCScrollView.sendMomentumEvents' of native type 'boolean'

Thanks for any help

Comment: i've got same issue, strangely on code that was working just fine yesterday. It stopped working after i added some unrelated library. I suspect i've picked up some updated library that causes it. Temporary walk around is to simply comment out throw in /node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactIOS/verifyPropTypes.js [:53]

Comment: That did it for now a least, thx

Comment: Thanks that worked for me to, if you find the solution or get more information on it please please link here will appreciate it.